# Java 8 Stream filtering and grouping by same expensive method call

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for a way to optimize a `Stream` processing in a clean way.

I have something like that:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(targetDir)) {
    Map<String, List<Path>> targetDirFilteredAndMapped = stream.parallel()                                                                                                
        .filter(path -> sd.containsKey(md5(path)))                                                                                                                    
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(path -> md5(path)));
} catch (IOException ioe) { // manage exception }
```

and since the `md5` function is quite expensive, I was wondering if there's a way to invoke it only once per file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tuples would be nice for that, if java had them. (and auto unpacking, to make it look nice)

Answer (score 12):

You can create some `PathWrapper` object that contains a `Path` instance and its corresponding `md5(path)`.

```
public class PathWrapper
{
    Path path;
    String md5; // not sure if it's a String
    public PathWrapper(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
        this.md5 = md5(path);
    }
    public Path getPath() {return path;}
    public String getMD5() {return md5;}
}
```

Then map your stream to `Stream<PathWrapper>`:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(targetDir)) {
    Map<String, List<Path>> targetDirFilteredAndMapped =
        stream.parallel() 
              .map(PathWrapper::new)
              .filter(path -> sd.containsKey(path.getMD5()))                                                                                                                    
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PathWrapper::getMD5,
                                             Collectors.mapping(PathWrapper::getPath,
                                                                Collectors.toList())));
} catch (IOException ioe) { /* manage exception */ }
```

Comment: You can even use `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` instead of an own class

Comment: @ArneBurmeister Good idea, I didn't know about that class. Though the method references would get quite long with that class name :)

Comment: or use `javafx.util.Pair` as wrapper class if we don't want to create a dedicated wrapper class

Comment: @NicolasFilotto if not inside a rich client using JavaFX I would not do so as you would run into problems when migrating to Java 9 where JavaFX becomes an optional part of the RT libs.

Answer (score 7):

If the `md5` operation is truly dominating the performance, you may consider leaving off the filtering here and just remove the nonmatching groups afterwards:

```
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(targetDir)) {
    Map<String, List<Path>> targetDirFilteredAndMapped = stream.parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> md5(p), HashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
    targetDirFilteredAndMapped.keySet().retainAll(sd.keySet());
} catch (IOException ioe) { 
    // manage exception
}
```

This, of course, temporarily requires more memory. If this is a concern, using a more complicated solution, like shown in the other answers, is unavoidable.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative of creating a dedicated class is to use the `collect` method directly, where you'll take care of doing the `md5` computation in the accumulator and where the combiner will take care of merging the entries.

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(targetDir)) {
    Map<String, List<Path>> targetDirFilteredAndMapped =
        stream.parallel()
              .collect(HashMap::new,
                       (m, p) -> {
                           String res = md5(p);
                           if(sd.containsKey(res)) {
                               m.computeIfAbsent(res, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(p);
                           }
                        },
                        (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.computeIfAbsent(k, k2 -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(v)));
} catch (IOException ioe) { 
    // manage exception
}
```

As [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) pointed out, you can optimize this by avoiding the creation of a new list using a better merging function:

```
(m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k,v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (l1,l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; }))
```

Comment: Not sure how the `HashMap::new` will deal with a parallel stream... Maybe there is some kind of guarantee that the merging is single threaded ?

Comment: @GPI It's the supplier function, so each thread will start with its own empty map to do its work with.

Comment: The merge function wastes resources by always using `addAll`, constructing a new list when there is no list in the first map. A better function would be `(m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k,v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (l1,l2)->{ l1.addAll(l2);return l1; } ))` (This is basically what the builtin `groupingBy` collector uses).

Comment: @Holger True! Thank you for your valuable input, as always ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use tuples for such cases.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Map<String, String> sd = Maps.newHashMap();
    Stream<Path> stream = Stream.empty();
    Map<String, List<Path>> targetDirFilteredAndMapped = stream.parallel()
        .map(path -> Tuple.tuple(path, md5(path)))
        .filter(tuple -> sd.containsKey(tuple.right()))
        .collect(groupingBy(Tuple::right,
                 mapping(Tuple::left,
                 toList())));
}

private static String md5(final Path path) {
        return "md5";
}
```

Unfortunaltely there's no tuple in java (like () in scala) so I've created such class:

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Tuple<L, R> {
    public static <L, R> Tuple<L, R> tuple(L left, R right) {
        return new Tuple<>(left, right);
    }

    private final L left;
    private final R right;

    private Tuple(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public L left() {
        return left;
    }

    public R right() {
        return right;
    }
}
```

You could also create some kind of private class that stores both Path and md5 but tuples are just faster to use.